# org mode tables slowed down by evil mode

Tags: org-mode, evil, org-table

I am trying to create a table in org-mode like that (`/` is where my cursor is)

```
| this is a test | foo | bar |
| ---------/---- | --- | --- |
```

If I now press enter, emacs hangs and I have to interrupt via C-g.

After debugging a while, I figured out that `replace-match` was not replacing the latest match, but seemingly random parts of the string when `evil-mode` was active. This causes an endless loop in `org-table-clean-line` and as a result, emacs freezes when I try to add a new row.

So my question is: what is causing the different behaviour of `replace-match` and how can I fix it so that I can use `evil-mode` without my tables freezing in `org-mode`?

I am using GNU Emacs 28.1 (build 1, x86_64-apple-darwin20.6.0, Carbon Version 164 AppKit 2022.6)
of 2022-05-03

Comment: Instead of profiling, you should turn on `debug-on-quit` and then reproduce the problem. When you are sure it is hung, press `C-g`. You should get a backtrace with the function that is causing the problem at the top. You might want to do it a few times, to make sure that it is the *same* function every time.

Comment: What's the *question*?

Comment: @Drew that's a fair question. I was frustrated and had no idea (or maybe energy) left how to tackle this. I had to write it down and ask _someone_ for direction. NickD's comment is a step into the right direction. I might close this question as "unclear" and pose a new one, as soon as I can pinpoint the error more specifically. What do you think?

Comment: I think you should be able to rephrase the title and perhaps the content to pose a question. You do have at least one question, don't you?

Comment: Sorry to ask, but what is this "Carbon" stuff on your installation? according to this https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carbon_(API) the Carbon was deprecated.

Comment: @Ian I am using this Mac Port: https://github.com/railwaycat/homebrew-emacsmacport Not sure where Carbon comes into play there.

Comment: Quoting from your link: ```> This provides a native GUI support for OS X 10.10 - macOS 12. Note that Emacs 23 and later already contain the official GUI support via the NS (Cocoa) port. So if it is good enough for you, then you don't need to try this.``` - it is Carbon, expressed in other words. Try instead a Cocoa version, e.g this: https://github.com/d12frosted/homebrew-emacs-plus.

Answer (score 0):

I can not answer the part regarding `replace-match`, but I found the underlying issue.

In my config I use `use-package` and `straight.el` to configure my packages. I had something along the following lines written there:

```
(use-package org
    :straight t
    :config
    [...]
)
```

Since `org` is built in, there's no need to pull it from straight. I could fix my problem by changing the configuration like that:

```
(use-package org
    :straight (:type built-in)
    :config
    [...]
)
```

Pulling `org` from straight fetches the latest version 9.5.4, whereas the built-in version is 9.5.2. Apparently some changes in 9.5.3 or 9.5.4 trigger the endless loop.

Digging a little deeper, this is a sample configuration that reproduces the problem:

```
;; ------ bootstrapping straight -------------

(defvar bootstrap-version)
(let ((bootstrap-file
       (expand-file-name "straight/repos/straight.el/bootstrap.el" user-emacs-directory))
      (bootstrap-version 5))
  (unless (file-exists-p bootstrap-file)
    (with-current-buffer
    (url-retrieve-synchronously
     "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/raxod502/straight.el/develop/install.el"
     'silent 'inhibit-cookies)
      (goto-char (point-max))
      (eval-print-last-sexp)))
  (load bootstrap-file nil 'nomessage))

(straight-use-package 'use-package)

;; -------- bootstrapping ends here ------------

(use-package evil
  :straight t
  :config (evil-mode))

(use-package evil-leader
  :straight t
  :config (global-evil-leader-mode))

(use-package org
  :straight t)
```

I could narrow it down to `evil`, `evil-leader` and `org` v9.5.4. If you start emacs with this configuration, create or open an org file and try to add a new row in a table, your emacs should freeze.

Comment: IIUC, you are saying that the problem arises when you use the latest version of Org mode, but it goes away if you use the built-in version. Can you specify exactly which version produces the error and which version you are now using? This might be a bug in latest Org mode: knowing which version works and which version does not should allow somebody to try to reproduce it and, if it is a bug, it should help narrow down the change that introduced it.

Comment: @NickD I added a couple more details. Should this be reported as a bug? I feel like I lack the skills to debug any further here.

Comment: I think you have enough details in your answer to open a bug report. It might be on the evil side, but it is more likely to be on the Org mode side I think. Just do `M-x org-submit-bug-report`, paste your question and your answer (and include a link to this question too) and send it in.